# Is there enough information in this question?

Tags: gas-laws

Here is the question:

> Some countries still measure liquid volumes in gallons. (1 gallon = 3.785 L). A test in America recently found that a certain car's engine produces on average 9.50 kg of $\ce{CO2}$, which is a Greenhouse gas. Calculate the annual production of $\ce{CO2}$ in kg if there are 40 million cars in the USA and each car covers a distance of 12 000 km at a consumption of 20 miles per gallon. (1 mile = 1.609 km)

I don't think there is as I work out the annual fuel consumption, but am unsure about how to proceed from there. I think this is because it is not actually stated what the 9.5 kg figure for the production of $\ce{CO2}$ refers to (e.g. per year, per gallon of fuel, etc.)

Comment: It seems that you are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

A gallon of gasoline weighs about 6.2 pounds, and is approximately (CH2)n. If combined with O2, the products would be 19.48 pounds (8.85 kg) of CO2 and 7.97 pounds of H2O. OK, so maybe the problem used slightly denser gasoline or it had less hydrogen in its composition. Close enough!

It seems that the problem assumes a familiarity with all the factors in the situation. Sometimes you have to read minds!